# Error running rails app on docker container of official Ruby image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I pulled official Ruby image from docker hub. Since the official Rails image has been deprecated, I felt like using using my rails development inside a Ruby container. Inside the Ruby container, I did `gem install rails --version=5.1.1` . I created a rails app and when I do `rails s`, it throws the following error. What is the problem? Do i need to install additional dependencies? Is this is a nodejs related issue, which I think is not pre- installed in the Ruby image?

```
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
:
:
from /home/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
:
:
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/blog/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /home/blog/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
:
:
from /home/blog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment, not enough points, but I can answer.

The gem installs and setup usually happen prior and during the setup of the container. Not afterwards manually like you are attempting to do.

Can you post up your Dockerfile so we can have a look?

Comment: i did not use a dockerfile. i built the container using docker run and then installed the rails gem.

Comment: Try using a Dockerfile Aayush, it's alot easier to get to work, and alot easier to share your work then, so others can help.  Also have a go with a docker-compose file as well, started to make alot more sense for me with those 2 files.